How to add labels into Desmos

Hi I believe this is Desmos 3d how to add labels into my project for any of my equations? I want to write notes underneath how to do it?

Under the little $+$ sign in the upper left, you can choose a note.

That being said, this is not really the correct forum for such technical software questions, and those tags are certainly not the correct ones.

When you click on a box to enter your numbers and stuff, you can also press the Enter key to open a new box below, then press the button with the quotation marks on your keyboard to immediately activate the "note" tab.

To write notes in Desmos, click the "+" in the upper left-hand corner,

Then click the "note" option,

Then a note tab should appear in Desmos like so:

Alternatively, type a double quote (") in an empty line. If you are asking for labels inside the $3$D environment, that is not possible now, but they may add that feature in a later update
